# Concourse CI Pipeline giving error :- Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, continuous-integration, pivotaltracker, concourse

I installed **Concourse CI** using **BOSH** deployment on **AWS**.

After successful installation i am able to see Concourse CI on browser.I have created **hello-world pipeline** using Concourse CI official page :- **http://concourse-ci.org/getting-started.html**

But when I am trying to run build for hello-world pipeline i am getting error :-

```
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection
```

Please let me know how i can fix this issue.Thanks in advance.
My CI Pipeline code :-

```
jobs:        
- name: hello-world     
  plan:      
  - task: say-hello    
    config:   
      platform: linux   
      image: "docker:///ubuntu"   
      run:  
        path: echo  
        args: ["Hello, world!"]
```

Comment: I am having this problem as well.

Comment: Did you get this solved? I am stuck at the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem too, but a little different.I use docker to install concourse ci. It fails with ping https://registry-1.docker.io/v2 always **timeout**. Finally, I found that the DNS address cause this problem. I bind specify the dns server address, then it works! So you should check your dns configuration. Hope this can help you!

You can still refer this link [https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/347]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Image for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1w4u.png)

You can use the following command to restart your docker-machine, then the network will reconnect:

```
$ docker-machine restart default
```

Result:
[image]

More info: https://forums.docker.com/t/error-response-from-daemon-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2/23741/10

Answer (score -4):

Close your agent like following:

[image]